# Ubuntu 20.04 - glitchy graphics

Tags: 20.04, intel-graphics

I started having big issues with my Ubuntu 20.04 on Thinkpad T440s.
Graphics started being really glitchy as seen on the screenshot.
It's not static parts of the screen but it happens on different parts so it's almost impossible to work anymore.

lspci gives the following for the graphics card (Intel HD Graphics 4400):
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
[image: glitche image]

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

(sorry, I'm new here so no enough reputation to post images inline)

Comment: Try this solution (actually, a workaround: it disables a power saving feature). https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185787/screen-redraw-issue-lenovo-yoga-s940-ubuntu-19-10-feels-laggish/1185841#1185841 Let us know if that worked for you (It does for me!)

Comment: The problem is with the 5.8.0-49 and -50 kernels. See my accepted answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333025/strange-graphics-issues-such-as-flickering-application-windows-and-inconsistent

Comment: @vanadium Please see my prior comment.

Comment: @heynnema thanks a lot! Works like a charm now.

Comment: @vanadium **i915.enable_psr=0** doesn't fix the problem with 5.8.0-50 for me.